# django-simple-captcha installing app in settings.py

Tags: django, django-apps

I'm trying to install django-simple-captcha (https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html)

It installed in pip correctly but I can't figure out how the next instruction, "add captcha to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py"

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'captcha',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

It doesn't seem to be able to find captcha when I add it this way? Am I missing something?

Comment: As it says, add `captcha` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.. replace `'captcha.apps'` with `'captcha'` only and follow further instructions

Comment: do I need to copy files into the project, or can python find the app that was installed by pip?

Comment: nope, you don't need to do anything with the original captcha app. PIP does that for you.

Comment: Pycharm is saying that 'captcha' is an unresolved reference, do I need to change the name to something else?

Comment: do not get blinded by IDE features, check if it is installed or not yourself. by importing it in console or reading you installed packages list in pip

Comment: captcha imports into the django shell, but when I run the sever it errors out saying     `raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.` Which makes me think that it can't find captcha app when it is trying to load the installed apps

Comment: Nevermind, my terminal and pycharm were using different interperters, I'm not very smart

Answer (score 0):

My terminal was using the virtualenv and pycharm was not... I am not a smart man